# Como Criar condicional em uma DIV p/ mudar conteúdo

Tags: html, html5, div, tabela-html

Estou tentando fazer uma condicional para exibir conteúdos dentro de uma `div`.
Meu site está com o `CSS` ajustável por tipo de navegador, mas isso só muda o formato (tamanho) de exibição!

Preciso **alterar o conteúdo** de uma determinada `div` para cada tipo de navegador.

Exemplo: se, acessando a página via celular (onde a `div` será ajustada por 
`with Breakpoints`) quero mostrar uma imagem X-para Celular com um link Y); caso contrário, acessando a página via navegador web (onde a div será ajustada por with Breakpoints) quero mostrar outra imagem Z-para WEB com um link W)...

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: faça com javascript

Comment: Não seu qual linguagem você esta usando, mas em PHP podes usar `$_SERVER` e capturar `HTTP_USER_AGENT`, apos é so criar um `switch` com cada tipo setando a imagem.

Comment: não é possível mudar o conteúdo com CSS, mas você pode mostrar/ocultar certas `<div>`s de acordo com tipo do navegador, o Bootstrap tem essas classes e você pode tomar como exemplo: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Para evitar textos em CAIXA ALTA, porém formatá-lo de maneira elegante, recomendo a leitura de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: acredito que seja isto que você quer: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html, basicamente ele faz uma requisição AJAX diferente para tamanhos de tela diferentes.

Comment: @re22 coloquei como resposta e dei alguma orientação de como usar apenas o Interchange de forma isolada.

Comment: Desculpem, mas as respostas ainda não ficaram claras...

Answer (score 4):

olha, você pode fazer isto usando um recurso do Zurb Foundation, no caso o `Interchange`, como o Zurb é todo modular, você pode baixar apenas ele.

Para baixar o mesmo, basta ir no seguinte [link](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation) e deixa selecionado apenas o `Interchange`

configurar ele é bem simples:

**HTML**

```
<div data-interchange="[URL Tela Pequena, (small)], [URL Tela Media, (medium)], [URL Tela Grande, (large)]">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).foundation();
```

um pequeno exemplo funcional usando Blobs:

```js
//inicio da criação dinamica dos links externos
var blobs = {};
blobs.telaPequena = new Blob(["<p>Tela Pequena</p>"], { type: "text/html" });
blobs.telaMedia = new Blob(["<p>Tela Media</p>"], { type: "text/html" });
blobs.telaGrande = new Blob(["<p>Tela Grande</p>"], { type: "text/html" });

var urls = {};
urls.telaPequena = URL.createObjectURL(blobs.telaPequena);
urls.telaMedia = URL.createObjectURL(blobs.telaMedia);
urls.telaGrande = URL.createObjectURL(blobs.telaGrande);   

var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.dataset.interchange = "" + 
    "[" + urls.telaPequena + ", (small)], " + 
    "[" + urls.telaMedia + ", (medium)], " + 
    "[" + urls.telaGrande + ", (large)]";
//termino da criação dinamica dos links externos

$(function () {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

fique a vontade para redimencionar a pagina e ver o conteudo mudar.

**DICA**

apenas mais uma coisa, você pode definir as suas proprias medias queries para usar com o plugin, não apenas `(small)`, `(medium)` ou `(large)`

```
$(document).foundation('interchange', {
  named_queries : {
    my_custom_query : 'only screen and (max-width: 200px)'
  }
});
```

Comment: Não conhecia Zurb Foundation, +1

Answer (score 0):

Desculpem minha ignorância, mas as respostas ainda não ficaram claras...

## Minha página (com as DIVs em questão) está assim:

(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        
    



    
        
        
        
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

=================================

## Tenho um CSS com o seguinte formato:

/* -------------------------------------------- *
 * Toolbar-web
 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .toolbar-web {
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
      background: #f4f4f4;
      padding: 5px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
    .toolbar-web:after {
      content: '';
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

```
.pager-no-toolbarweb {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.pager-no-toolbarweb ~ .pager-no-toolbarweb {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.toolbar-web,
.pagerweb {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: #636363;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.toolbar-web label,
.pager-no-toolbarweb label {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

}

/* -------------------------------------------- *
 * Toolbar-wap
 */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .toolbar-wap {
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
      background: #f4f4f4;
      padding: 5px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
    .toolbar-wap:after {
      content: '';
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

```
.pager-no-toolbarwap {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.pager-no-toolbarwap ~ .pager-no-toolbarwap {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.toolbar-wap,
.pagerwap {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: #636363;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.toolbar-wap label,
.pager-no-toolbarwap label {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

}

=================================

Como Ocultar as DIVs da classe: "toolbar-wap" e "toolbar-web"